# How to follow the evolution of position in SERP in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Is there a way to see the evolution in time of the position in search engine results? In Google Webmaster Tools I can see the different positions where my page was showed but is there a way to "sort it in time"?

E.G. I see this:

[image]

But is there a way to see chronologicaly the evolution? And what is the actual position as of now? "6 to 10", "2nd page" or "3rd page +"?

PS: I mean directly in GWT (I don't want to buy any SEO software...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible to set a time period when you drill down by search queries in Google's Webmaster Tools but it will show the last months change in impressions/clicks by default.

You'd be looking at 3rd party software and tools to achieve what you're after.